# Best practices for LOGGING in microservices architecture

Tags: logging, microservices

What is the preferred way of handling logging in microservices architecture?

1. Have an individual logging mechanism for each microservice
2. Have one logging mechanism and have each microservice use it

Comment: Generally we use sidecar pattern for logging. Means a separate container is running by the side of application to avoid latency .  But if it's a simple application you can use one logging container for all the applications . Really depends on the type and nature of the application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/sidecar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centralised logging is what you want to achieve at the end. I would look into direction of **ELK Stack** with **Filebeat** as a sidecar container.

It might look like this:

[image]

1. A microservice logs everything into log files.
2. Filebeat, run as a sidecar container for this microservice, has access to log files and ship them into Logstash.
3. Logstash receives logs from Filebeat, transform and then send them to  elasticsearch index.
4. You can access your centralised logs with Kibana.